# Faded Effect Using CSS and Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Please look at the link given below to understand my question.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B52AyCZWoFl_TjdLQzNRQUFtaG8/edit?usp=sharing

The thing is, when the user clicks the help button, a box type of a area appears in the center of the screen and the remaining area behind the box is still visible, even though the remaining area looks faded. I know that we can make one div appear on top of another, by using z-index, but I am not able to understand how can I make the remaining area look faded.

Can someone please demonstrate this with a simple example. Thanks

Comment: It's called a modal window, or modal dialog. Google it.

Comment: check this link , it will be a good read http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/04/techniques-for-creating-modal-windows/

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal

Comment: If you look they basically create a div with a gray background and then they set the opacity attribute to give that fadded effect.

Comment: @j08691 if you can make an answer, then I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "fading" effect is probably just a semi-opaque overlay. The "box type thing" is called a "modal window", or just "modal".

There are *many* ways to achieve this. Here is a very simple example using jquery:

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hy5uk/2/)

```
<button id="trigger">Click me</button>
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="modal">Hello. I'm a modal window</div>
```

---

```
.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}

.modal {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
}
```

---

```
$('#trigger').click(function() {
   $('.overlay,.modal').fadeIn(300); 
});

$('#close').click(function() {
   $('.overlay,.modal').fadeOut(300); 
});
```